# Great Lakes Earth Series

Tags: discussion, blog, reference

Let us say that, in the future, some scientists have created satellites capable of something that seems science fiction for now — punching the walls of the universe to study an alternate reality. By that scenario, some hundreds of “alternate Earths” from hundreds of alternate universes would already have been discovered and meticulously studied. As much as half of them would still be ruled by humans, unfolded by events that turned out differently. One universe, for example, had an Earth where 9/11 never happened, or where the outcome of the Revolutionary and Civil Wars ended up differently.

One of the most interesting to note was a planet that scientists call “Alternate Earth 111”, known to the public as “Great Lakes Earth”.

Why?

Because at first glance, it seemed that almost every continent is dominated by lakes, even those larger than the Great Lakes that we have in North America. What is its history? What points of divergence would we expect to see in this particular variation?

This proved to be a long, backbreaking investigation because when our alt-satellites picked up Great Lakes Earth, it has discovered traces of civilization — traces roughly 100,000 years old. However, after years of picking up the pieces and speculating on the rest, we believe that we have mapped the entire geography and the best of the history of Great Lakes Earth.

As with the Anatomically Correct Series or the Creating a Realistic World Series, this is an ongoing process and will be subject to edit or add.

Comment: You could also link your Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: @Vincent  The majority of them don't have answers.  Some of them were closed.  All the geography and astronomy involved are in the links.

Comment: I'd suggest writing these links in an answer rather than in the question. While not a problem now, when you get into the larger numbers it will

Comment: @JohnWDailey while true, your questions still contain a lot of information by themselves. And they explain much of the logic behind each change. I think it would still be worthwhile to add all the related questions, even if they can be accessible from other means (also include looking at your profile).

Answer (score 1):

#### On other sites

[Great Lakes Earth:  Geography](https://medium.com/universe-factory/great-lakes-earth-geography-372bce96d642#.8atotmlma)

[Great Lakes Earth:  Solar System](https://medium.com/@johndailey/the-solar-system-of-great-lakes-earth-1ac15b6c439d#.irc168w7p)

[Asia, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Asia-Great-Lakes-Earth-Collage-623800746)

[Africa, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Africa-Great-Lakes-Earth-collage-623802775)

[Pangaea, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Pangaea-Great-Lakes-Earth-633206598)

[Timeline of Great Lakes Earth's Geological History](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Timeline-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-s-Geological-History-633801492)

[Bering Land Bridge, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Bering-Land-Bridge-Great-Lakes-Earth-634024797)

[Tethys Sea, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Tethys-Sea-Great-Lakes-Earth-634199234)

[Europe, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Europe-Great-Lakes-Earth-634200102)

[Siberian Traps, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Siberian-Traps-Great-Lakes-Earth-634202155)

[Ordovician Extinction Event, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Ordovician-Extinction-Event-GLE-634278474)

[The Permian Big Freeze, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Permian-Big-Freeze-Great-Lakes-Earth-634369334)

[The Die-Odd, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Die-Odd-Great-Lakes-Earth-634460673)

[The Cretaceous Thermal Maximum, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Cretaceous-Thermal-Maximum-Great-Lakes-Earth-634701642)

[The Great Dying, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Great-Dying-Great-Lakes-Earth-634886020)

[The Icing of Antarctica, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Icing-of-Antarctica-Great-Lakes-Earth-635045542)

[The Tethys Salinity Crisis, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Tethys-Salinity-Crisis-Great-Lakes-Earth-635111219)

[The Big Freeze, Great Lakes Earth](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/The-Big-Freeze-Great-Lakes-Earth-635252533)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Plants**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Plants-635313233)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Invertebrates**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Invertebrates-635841313)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Fish**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Fish-636014132)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Amphibians**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Amphibians-636187933)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Reptiles**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Reptiles-636323027)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Birds**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Birds-636399557)

[Wildlife of Great Lakes Earth:  **Mammals**](http://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/art/Wildlife-of-Great-Lakes-Earth-Mammals-636624874)

#### On Stack Exchange

[Hot(ter)house Cretaceous](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55373/hotterhouse-cretaceous)

[Changing the Danger Zone of Tornado Alley](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49506/changing-the-danger-zone-of-tornado-alley/55484#55484)

[The Bering Land Bridge, Open for PERMANENT Business](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55054/the-bering-land-bridge-open-for-permanent-business/55082?noredirect=1#comment155404_55082)

[Alternate Pangaea](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/alternate-pangaea?noredirect=1#comment152885_54301)

[Russia's Alternate Geological History](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54173/russias-alternate-geological-history/54389#54389)

[Biggest Ben in the World](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53496/biggest-ben-in-the-world)

[An Edenic Outback?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/an-edenic-outback)

[More Land to India, More Height to Tibet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52506/more-land-to-india-more-height-to-tibet)

[Lake Makgadikgadi, 21st Century](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52403/lake-makgadikgadi-21st-century)

[Sahara Savanna?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52347/sahara-savanna)

[If Lady Liberty's Skin Were Bronze](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51601/if-lady-libertys-skin-were-bronze)

[Larger Lady Liberty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42906/larger-lady-liberty?rq=1)

[Greenland--Not So Green Anymore](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/50596/greenland-not-so-green-anymore)

[A Culture Run by Spider Silk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/49037/a-culture-run-by-spider-silk)

[Steampunk Architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48921/steampunk-architecture)

[If Apocryphal Texts Never Were Apocryphal, How Would This Affect Christianity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/if-apocryphal-texts-never-were-apocryphal-how-would-this-affect-christianity)

[How This Alternate Solar System Influences the Milankovitch Cycle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46378/how-this-alternate-solar-system-influences-the-milankovitch-cycle)

[New York City as Imagined by Hugh Ferriss](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/new-york-city-as-imagined-by-hugh-ferriss)

[The Solar System, Great Lakes Earth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39493/the-solar-system-great-lakes-earth)

[The Baltic Plain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34492/turning-the-baltic-sea-into-the-baltic-plain)

[No One Leaves Africa Without His Bow](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33730/no-one-leaves-africa-without-his-bow)

[The Winter of a Hundred Years](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21797/the-winter-of-a-hundred-years)

[The First of Today's Mammals--Who Began Whom?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51595/the-first-of-todays-mammals-who-began-whom?noredirect=1#comment90236_51595)

Comment: I edited your post to indicate to which site support those links point to. I think it makes it clearer for anyone whether to expect a WB question on SE or go somewhere else (in this case, a blog). But if you disagree, feel free to revert it :)

Answer (score -2):

Let's slow and simplify things down.  First, I need feedback and verification on geography and astronomy.

[Geography](https://medium.com/universe-factory/great-lakes-earth-geography-372bce96d642#.l1qiy88ji)

**The** ***Cause*** **is set.  Now to investigate the** ***Effects*** **these changes have on climate, weather, landscape and ocean current circulation.**

[Solar System](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-solar-system-of-great-lakes-earth-1ac15b6c439d#.ygnainzfj)

**The** ***Cause*** **is set.  Now to investigate the** ***Effects*** **these changes have on Earth’s nightscape, its Milankovitch cycles and even the asteroid belt (if it could still exist.)**

Comment: Why the downvote?